# Passing a string value as a parameter HttpClient Post

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, httpclient

I need to pass a string value as text in a Post.

I have tried the following

```
string content = "91237932,xy91856,0,0";
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AttributesApi"] + $"/api/UserProfiles/UpdateUserProfileFromIAM", new StringContent(content));
```

This is what I have to work with (can't change it as is existing)  but the value is null

```
[HttpPost("UpdateUserProfileFromIAM")]
public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateUserProfileFromIAM(string attributes)
{
    //attributes null
}
```

How can do this HttpClient post so that it is a simple string value?

Comment: depends what bit you are struggling with? if its reading the result, I have posted an answer. If not then please clarify

Comment: try to put it inside a root class like : ``public class Root{public string  attributes{get;set;}}`` and change the signature like : ``UpdateUserProfileFromIAM(Root root)``

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is that you can't read the result then try this:

```
public async Task<string> GetData() 
{
  string content = "91237932,xy91856,0,0";
  using var client = new HttpClient();
  var response = await client.PostAsync(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AttributesApi"] + $"/api/UserProfiles/UpdateUserProfileFromIAM", new StringContent(content));
  return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```